# Getting angle between 2 lines in swift

Tags: ios, swift, line, angle

I need to know how to get the angle between 2 lines in Swift, I’ve looked into dot product but you need the fall of each line for that I believe, I would have CGPoints for start and finish of line a and line b but need to know the angle between them. Thanks in advance.[image: i need the angle between these 2 poorly drawn lines, these will be drawn using drawLine in app]

Comment: Can you provide sample data and what you have tried and what you're having an issue with?

Comment: share your code, I think you just get the angle using the position y/x in each line and after that, you should only subtract both angle.

Comment: That's basic maths/geometry. There are formula available once you get two points for each line.

Comment: Here some explanation how to calculate an [angle between two vectors](https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/vectors/angleBetween/. a vector (x, y) means that you take a point, advance by x horizontally and by y vertically.